# Word or phrase when a person vanishes when you look away

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase when you think you see a person, look away, then look back and the person is gone?

For example, I thought I saw my friend as I walked into a cafe. I looked at my phone, looked back up and he wasn't there. The table was empty, like there had been no one sitting at it.

I asked a coworker if he knew of a word or phrase and he told of a similar situation; he walked in the front door of his home, saw his roommate in the living room, turned right to walk into the kitchen and his roommate was in the kitchen.

He called this phenomenon "A glitch in the Matrix" or seeing a doppelgänger.

I don't think doppelgänger is the correct term, though.

Is there a better phrase or word to describe these mirages or phantoms we're seeing?

Comment: hallucination? Does it have to always describe when you think you see something but nothing is there?

Comment: @Hank Yes. I think I see something, but as soon as I look away then back it's gone. So, the object I'm seeing was never there to being with

Comment: In that case, I think [hallucination](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hallucination) would fit, although it does usually carry a connotation of being caused by a mental illness or drugs.

Comment: @Hank Yeah, that's why I was hoping there was a word that would denote we are NOT mentally unstable, like de ja vu (but that's not the correct phrase)

Comment: "apparition" is another word for a ghostlike or unexplained image -- not necessarily a fleeting 'now you see it, now you don't" vision though

Answer (score 2):

***Glimpse*** -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glimpse)

> (noun) a brief look at someone or something:
>   *He caught a glimpse of her face.*
>
> (verb) *I glimpsed her walking back from town.*

Comment: Good choice; "fleeting glimpse" is also often used, especially in mystery or detective fiction!

Comment: @NVZ "As I glimpsed around the room I saw a fleeting apparition of Bob".  That is exactly what happened! But somehow, "I thought I saw Bob at the cafe, but it was glitch in the Matrix" sounds cooler :-D

Comment: @EnglishStudent - [You’re in good company](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/pinkfloyd/comfortablynumb.html) *When I was a child I caught a fleeting glimpse, Out of the corner of my eye, I turned to look but it was gone, I cannot put my finger on it now, The child is grown, The dream is gone*

Comment: @Jim thanks for the link! I have been reading so much English for the last 33 years since age 4 that I am continually struck by remembered word associations and combinations. You tell me glimpse, I tell you fleeting! The verses you quoted are very evocative.

Comment: @Kearney Taaffe *glitch in the matrix* sounds cooler indeed!

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe Can one 'glimpse around'? As a verb, *glimpse* means 'To get a glimpse of' (per Chambers phone App), it's an instantaneous rather than continuous thing.

Comment: @Spagirl It's rare. But some writers used it. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22glimpse+around%22&tbm=bks&biw=1600&bih=770). They use it not as a verb, however. They did not glimpse around, they [took a glimpse] around some places.

Comment: @Spagirl according to Apple's dictionary **see or perceive briefly or partially** _e.g. he glimpsed a figure standing in the shade._

Answer (score 1):

"He vanished [into thin air](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/into+thin+air)" is an idiom that describes someone disappearing without notice. The opposite "appeared out of thin air" also works as the opposite, although [it's used slightly less](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into%20thin%20air%2C%20out%20of%20thin%20air&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinto%20thin%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20thin%20air%3B%2Cc0).

As per discussion below, [apparition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apparition) works in this scenario as a noun for the person who vanishes.

Comment: Is there a noun that can be used? I want to use it in a sentence like, "I saw an [insert appropriate noun] of Bob yesterday"

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe ah, I think [apparition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apparition) would work then.

Comment: I guess "fleeting apparition" would be the best phrase :-)

Comment: @rosslh Apparition, excellent!

Answer (score 1):

> **abscond**
> [ab-skond]/
> verb (used without object)
>
> 1. to depart in a sudden and secret manner, especially to avoid capture and legal prosecution.

If you think that the person was actually there and left swiftly.